# Why is there no choice for cooperative scheduling?

Tags: process, scheduling

Operating System Concepts says

> CPU-scheduling decisions may take place under the following four
> circum- stances:
>
> 1. When a process switches from the running state to the waiting state (for example, as the result of an I/O request or an invocation of
>    wait() for the termination of a child process)
> 2. When a process switches from the running state to the ready state (for example, when an interrupt occurs)
> 3. When a process switches from the waiting state to the ready state (for example, at completion of I/O)
> 4. When a process terminates
>
> For situations 1 and 4, there is **no choice in terms of scheduling**. A new process (if one exists in the
> ready queue) must be selected for execution. There is a
> **choice**, however, for situations 2 and 3.
>
> When scheduling takes place only under circumstances 1 and 4, we say
> that the scheduling scheme is nonpreemptive or cooperative. Otherwise,
> it is preemptive.

What does "choice in terms of scheduling" mean?

Why is there no choice for cooperative scheduling, and there may be for preemptive scheduling?

I think that whether scheduling is preemptive or not,

- the running process always gives up the CPU (so no choice), and
- there is always a choice to make to select one process from the ready queue to run.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text says that when there is no choice,

> A new process (if one exists in the ready queue) must be selected for execution.

I take this to mean that the choice being discussed isn’t directly about which process to schedule next, but rather whether the process being examined can be scheduled. In cases 1 and 4, it can’t. In cases 2 and 3, it can.

The cooperative v. preemptive terminology used here seems weird to me; cooperative scheduling usually means that processes yield control voluntarily, but interpreting “being blocked” and “terminating” as cooperative scheduling is somewhat far-fetched in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that changing the state of a process from running or waiting to ready can only be done by preemptive scheduling?

Comment: The “running to ready” transition is characteristic of preemptive scheduling, if it’s external; in cooperative scheduling, such a transition is possible when the running process yields. The “waiting to ready” transition isn’t specific to preemptive scheduling; in a cooperative model which yields on I/O, you’d need such a transition too.

Answer (score 1):

In cases 1 & 4 the process has no work to do (in case 1 yet, in case 4 ever) and therefore can't be run by the scheduler.  i.e. there's not choice to be made: run or don't run... it's always don't run.  There's a choice in the cases of 2 and 3 because the scheduler has to decide 'do I run this process or a different one?'  But only a preemptive scheduler will make that choice, a cooperative scheduler will wait until the running process is in state 1 (i.e. waiting for i/o or yielding) or 4 (terminated either successfully or with an error)